# How to understand the change of basis in a differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $w:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow Mat(n,\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function, $R_{ij}$ be a fixed skew-symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix, and $A\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider the equation $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} - \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_j {R}_{ij} x^j\right)^2 w + Aw = 0.$$

My question is, if one wants to solve for $w$, why is it sufficient to take $R_{ij}$ to be block-diagonal, consisting of $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric blocks? I know that a skew-symmetric matrix can always be block-diagonalised this way, but am having a hard time writing down rigorously what the solution to the equation would be if $R$ was changed to a block-diagonal form, say $P^{-1} RP$.

I'm looking for a proof that shows something like, if $w$ solves the above equation, then $P^{-1}wP$ solves the equation with $R$ replaced by $P^{-1}RP$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is simpler than I thought: if $w$ is a solution to this equation then $w$ itself will also solve the equation after an orthogonal change of basis (which one can choose to render $R$ block-diagonal).

To see this, first observe that it's actually a scalar equation in the entries of $w$, so it suffices to show this for $w\in\mathbb{R}$. One shows after some calculation that the Laplacian $\Delta$ has the same form after an orthogonal basis change, and one verifies that same goes for $\sum_{i,j}R_{ij}x^j \partial_i$ and $\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\sum_j R_{ij}x^j = \sum_i R_{ii}$. The details are tedious but the story has a happy ending.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - Consider the matrix $M:=P^{-1}RP$, where $P$ is orthogonal, i.e. $P^{-1}=P^{\text{T}}$. You are not saying that if $w:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow Mat(n,\mathbb{R})$ satisfies$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} - \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_j {R}_{ij} x^j\right)^2 w + Aw = 0,$$then also$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} - \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \frac{1}{4}\sum_j {M}_{ij} x^j\right)^2 w + Aw = 0,$$or are you?

Comment: @Filippo It's been a while, but what I was trying to say was that if $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)^T=P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$, then
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j}M_{ij}u^j\right)^2 w+Aw=0.$$
So I was claiming that not only is the Laplacian rotation-invariant, but so is the operator $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j}R_{ij}x^j\right)^2$ for any skew-symmetric $R$.

Comment: I was very happy to see that you replied. I think I understand: $w\mapsto w\circ (\text{id}_\mathbb{R},P)$ is a bijection between the set of solutions to the differential equation from your question and the set of solutions to this differential equation with $R$ replaced by $M$, right?